# how to setup amazon cognito to create temporary security token for a long term access key in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I read about it on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ but I am not clear, can anyone summaries the fact with example in javascript or any related link

Comment: Actually, I dont want to hard code my security keys in the javascript code for security purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is vaery helpfull..got It after a long

- https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/

and some recommendatios:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you should not hard code your AWS credentials in mobile or javascript app. I would advise you to use Amazon Cognito for such use cases. Please start with reading the documentation.

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html

Comment: I need a full workig example to understand the flow..I have read those docs many times but I'm confused about how to do it.